# BrokenProcessPool error in concurrent.futures Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, spyder, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to speed up my code by trying to make use of my full CPU power (as it is stuck somewhere around 15% max), by using the concurrnet.futures package in Python. However, I'm running into the same *BrokenProcessPool* error no matter what I try...

I've been through **a lot** of the questions posed on this site and have tried implementing every sollution I understood (I'm not that experienced yet), but cannot seem to work around this error.

So what I am trying to do is import a **HUGE** .csv file and filter it based on certain criteria. Now I know the way I am doing this is probably not the most logical, but I am also trying to learn how to do multiprocessing for future sitations.

My code is as follows;

```
'Load Master Data'
MasterData = pd.read_csv('FINAL MASTER DATA.csv')
MasterData.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
print('Data Loaded')
```

This loads in the file into a pandas dataframe with over 1.5 million rows and 18 columns of data.

```
'Format Forecast Date'
ForecastinWk = pd.DataFrame()
ForecastinWk['WkYr'] = MasterData.apply(lambda x: str(x['Forecasted in Wk']) + str('-') + str(x['Forecasted in Yr']), axis = 1)
print('Weeks & Years gathered')
ForecastinWk['WkYr'] = ForecastinWk['WkYr'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime('1-' + x, '%w-%W-%Y'))
print('WkYr formatted')
```

This section of code then formats the dates section into my required format.

```
def UseRowSelector(i, Masterdata, ForecastinWk):

        print(i)
        print('Determining whether to use row')
        MasterDataForecastedMonth = MasterData.loc[i,'Forecast for Month']
        LeadtimeDate = ForecastinWk.loc[i,'Date']
        if MasterDataForecastedMonth == LeadtimeDate:
            UseRow = True
        else:
            UseRow = False

        return UseRow,i
```

I am thus expecting this seciton of code to return either [True, Nr] or [False, Nr], as well as print 'i' and the text 'Determining whether to use row' (neither of which appear in the console).

```
def main(MasterData, ForecastinWk):

    MasterDataIndexList = list(MasterData.index)
    UseRows = pd.DataFrame()
    print('creating multiple processes')
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        print('executor created')
        future_to_index = {executor.submit(UseRowSelector, i, MasterData, ForecastinWk): i for i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}
        print('future created')
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_index):
            print('selected future')
            UseRow = future_to_index[future]
            Result = future.result()
            try:
                UseRows.loc[Result[1],0] = Result[0]
                print(Result[1])
            except:
                print('error')

    return UseRows
```

This section should call prep the data and call the UseRowSelector function. Since the data has over 1.5 million rows, I was trying to use multiprocessing to allow different CPU cores to perform the UseRowSelector function for different rows (so they are not dependent on each other).

Then the below should run for the different forecasting leadtime timeframes and prep the data for processing, before calling the actual multiprocessing function and later saving the output to a .csv file.

```
'Set Forecast Leadtime in wks'
for Leadtime in [5,10,15,20,25,30]:
    print(str('LEAD TIME --------------------  ' + str(Leadtime) + ' Weeks  --------------------'))

    ForecastinWk['Date'] = ForecastinWk['WkYr'].apply(lambda x: x + pd.DateOffset(weeks = Leadtime))
    print('Dates offset')
    ForecastinWk['Date'] = ForecastinWk['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%b %Y'))  
    print('Dates formatted')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print('name is main')
        UseRows = main(MasterData, ForecastinWk)

    print('Creating Master Data Section')
    MasterDataSelection = MasterData[UseRows.iloc[:,0]]

    MasterDataSelection.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)

    MasterDataSelection.to_csv(str('MasterDataDelen/' + str(Leadtime) + 'Wk Leadtime.csv'), index = False)
    MasterDataSelection.to_csv(str('MasterDataDelen/' + str(Leadtime) + 'Wk Leadtime - Acc.csv'))
    print('excel created')
```

Based on answers to other posters I added the `if __name__ = '__main__'` section and made sure the full required data is passed to the called functions...

If I try to run the sections manually; I can run the program till the print('selected future') section - so when I run the future.result() it will pose the error: *`BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending`*

If I try to run the full script at once (F5) I will still see the 'selected future' print statement being printed, but my CPU usage thereafter drops to 0% and I can't see anything happen - no errors are raised but python keeps processing (If I try to abort nothing happens...)

Anyone who knows what I could be doing wrong? I'm on Windows using Spyder (Python 3.7).

Thanks!

Comment: I think they mean, if main, should be at bottom of code, with 0 indent, see example 17.4.3.1: https://documentation.help/Python-3.7/concurrent.futures.html

Comment: Hi Peter, I'm not sure on what exactly could be going wrong, but a tip for using concurrent futures processpool in your situation (which might be the problem, and also is likely the cause of the cpu going to 0% and nothing happening):

When you call ProcessPoolExecutor, it will attempt to fork your current process *including all current object*.  I believe the object copying to the new processes uses pickle()

...if you have in memory a huge number of objects (as it seems is your case) then the object copy takes a huge amount of time/resources

Comment: So it's possible the object copying to the new processes is what's causing your problems.

In your situation you may need to drop down to using the lower-level mulitprocesing module, and 'manually' fork 'empty' processes - and only pass the pieces of data needed for the processing.

Comment: So perhaps try your code first with only a small set of sample data - not the full 1.5 million records - first and see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks NonoLondon and @Richard for your answers, it seems as if the amount of data was indeed far to large for my computer to handle. I've found a workaround, but thanks for the comments anyway!